# Оператор re.search выводит none

Tags: python, python-3.x, re, python-docx

Пытаюсь создать нечто похожее на парсер word документов. Задача - находить в docx таблицах строку, обозначающую ИНН организации и выводить 10тизначное число из ячейки справа

Возможный вид таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал вот так:

```
import os
import docx
import re 
from docx import Document
doc = docx.Document("D:/Python/sample.docx")

for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text)         
            WordINNfull=re.search(r"(ИНН)\s(\d{10})", cell.text)
print(WordINNfull)
```

Выхлоп получается такой

```
Полное и сокращенное наименование
Общество с ограниченной ответственностью «»
ООО «»
Организационно-правовая форма
Общество с ограниченной ответственностью
Адрес юридический
444444, Московская область, г. Москва…………………………………
Адрес местонахождения и почтовый адрес
444444, Московская область, г. Москва…………………………………
Руководитель (должность, ФИО)
Директор – Иванов Иван Иванович, 
Действует на основании Устава
ОГРН
1111111111111
ОКПО
11111111
ОКАТО
11111111111
ОКТМО
11111111111
Номера контактных телефоном и факсов
8-800-555-35-35
Адрес электронной почты
ya@.ru
ИНН/КПП 
ИНН 1111111111/ КПП 111111111
Полные банковские реквизиты
Сбербанк 
р/сч 1111111111111111111111111
БИК 1111111111111111  
к/с 11111111111111111111
None
>>>
```

Пробовал менять шаблон. Например `"\d"` выдает `re.Match object; span=(36, 37), match='4'`, но просто шаблон "ИНН" возвращает None.

Пните пожалуйста в нужную сторону!

Comment: Подозреваю что у вас кодировка текста и программы разная. Распечатайте рядом со строкой из ячейки шаблон регулярного выражения.

Comment: Попробуй после всех (for) поставить (continue) или (break) .
Можно ещё в книге (Мэтт Харрисон как устроен питон 96 стр. открываешь и там все про None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто. Вы каждую строку переназначаете переменную `WordINNfull`, соответственно, по итогу вы получаете поиск только в последней строке (None). Рабочий код выглядит так:

```py
import os
import docx
import re 
from docx import Document
doc = docx.Document("D:/Python/sample.docx")

for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text)         
            WordINNfull=re.search(r"(ИНН)\s(\d{10})", cell.text)
            if WordINNfull:
                print(WordINNfull)
```